# Android Layout align gender icon with age on facebox

Tags: android, android-layout, face-detection

[image]

I used canvas for image to draw rectangle on face detected area and age text on top.

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
canvas.drawRect(left, top, left + width, top + height, paint);
canvas.drawText(myText, left + width / 2,(float) (top - 10), paint);
```

Now I'm trying to align gender icon with age text inside image where age is showing.
Other problem is face detected box might be small, how can I re-size my TextView(icon + age) accordingly.

```
    TextView txtView=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    txtView.setText(String.valueOf((int)json.getDouble("age")));
    txtView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
    txtView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey_dark));
    if (json.getDouble("sex") >= 0.5) {
        txtView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.maleicon, 0, 0, 0);
    } else {
        txtView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.femaleicon, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(150, 110);
    txtView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    LL.addView(txtView);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use framelayout ( relativelayout over image) and align it . then resize the image differently and put it in linearlayout with textview.

Comment: Thanks, I tried by following your instruction, it still not aligned well http://tinypic.com/r/16i8x7o/8 kindly give me a tip to align

Comment: In relativelayout you can align linearlayout(age+gender icon) over the canvas box view. use .............android:layout_above
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_above